# Unable to install GConf2 in AWS EC2 AMI

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver, yum, gconf

I have setup an AWS EC2 instance [Amazon Linux AMI 2017.03.1 (HVM)] and whenever I try to check the version of chromedriver (downloaded 2.30 from [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.30/), has enough privileges to run also because `stat -c "%a %n" chromedriver` gives `755 chromedriver` ) using the command

```
chromedriver --version
```

I get the below error :

```
error while loading shared libraries: libgconf-2.so.4: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Also the result of `ldd chromedriver` is :

```
libgconf-2.so.4 => not found
```

I came to know that the above library is provided by `GConf2` (refer [here](https://fedora.pkgs.org/26/fedora-x86_64/GConf2-3.2.6-17.fc26.x86_64.rpm.html))
So I ran the command `yum install Conf2`
and I am stuck with the below error :

```
# yum install GConf2
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main    | 2.1 kB  00:00:00
amzn-updates | 2.3 kB  00:00:00
No package GConf2 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Note :

1. I am running the commands as a root user!
2. Tried to do `yum clean all`
   and `yum update` and updated all the packages and still getting the
   error
3. Also tried `yum provides */libgconf-2.so.4` , getting error : `Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper No matches found`

Answer (score -1):

I installed the Gconf2 following [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=229187)

Comment: The link is broken. You should always copy at least a fragment showing the relevant part.